# How do I make a list of all members in a discord server using discord.py?

Tags: python, server, discord, discord.py

I am writing a discord bot and I came across this error when trying to pull all the members from a server with the command !members in on_message event:

```
elif message.content.startswith('!members'):
    x = server.Server.members
    for member in x:
        print(member)
```

I want this command to pull all members and print them out in the console but I get the error

> TypeError: 'property' object is not iterable

when I type the command in the discord channel. Could anyone help me make a list of all members in the channel that I can have for further use?

Comment: Hi, I noticed the [question you asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51671433) a few minutes ago was deleted. Here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/CPHPython/pen/xJzVdZ) with the correction you needed.

Answer (score 7):

You need an instance of a server to get the members list from it.

Assuming this code appears in `on_message(message)`, you should be able to change your

```
x = server.Server.members
```

to

```
x = message.server.members
```

Note that using `Server` with a capital S will return the class definition, whereas using the `server` property (lowercase s) from the message will retrieve an instance of Server.

If you're using a version >= 1.0.0, this will be

```
x = message.guild.members
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

```py
elif message.content.startswith('!members'):
    x = message.server.members
    for member in x:
        print(member.name) # you'll just print out Member objects your way.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it so that the code is shorter

```
elif message.content.startswith('!members'):
    print(", ".join([member.name for member in message.server.members])) #You do the list with names of roles and print this without cycle
```

Answer (score 0):

The `x = message.server.members` is changed to `x = message.guild.members`