# Delete all user information from JSON Discord PY

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to reset everybody in the discord server's JSON information for "prize" when !reset is typed in chat. I know how to do it on an individual basis but not everyone.

```
def reset_prize(user: discord.User, prize: int):
    id = user.id
    if id not in stats:
        stats[id] = {}
    stats[id]["prize"] = 0
    print("{} prizes were reset to 0".format(user.name))
    save_stats()

@client.event
async def on_message(message, user=discord.User):
    if message.content.startswith("!reset"):
            x = message.server.members
            for member in x:
                reset_prize(member, 0)
```

Comment: If you know how to do it for one user, then you just need to know how to loop through all the users and do it for each of them one by one I imagine. Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47733376/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-all-members-in-a-discord-server-using-discord-py

Comment: Thanks so much, edited the code to reflect what works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `.clear()` attribute of the dict

```py
me={
    "name1":12,
    "name2":123,
    "ages":{
        "1":12,
        "1":111
    }
}


me['ages'].clear() #clear all the items inside the obj `ages
me.clear() #clear everything inside the `me` dict
print(me)
>>> {}
```

Comment: Thank you for this knowledge! This is very helpful to know.