# Discord PY getting all members of a server

Tags: discord, discord.py

Im pretty new to discord.py and would like to get the ids of all the people in the discord server that the bot is used in.

Thanks, 
Aarav

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make a list of all members in a discord server using discord.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47733376/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-all-members-in-a-discord-server-using-discord-py)

Comment: No, I am using rewrite which may have some issues. Running the suggested code from the link you posted about says: message object has no attribute server.

Comment: Use `guild` instead of `server`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First use should get `guild` object from `ctx.guild` in **command** event, `message.guild` in **on_message** event, etc. Then choose the sample below.

The sample to go through all members and do some stuff

```py
for member in guild.members:
    id = member.id

    # Do stuff here
```

The sample to get a list of all members ids

```py
ids = [member.id for member in guild.members]
```

The sample to get an itterator of all members ids

```py
def get_all_members_ids(guild):
    for member in guild.members:
        yield member.id

# And then use it like this
for id in get_all_members_ids(guild):
    # Do stuff here
```