# How to choose a random person discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I have been trying to make a command for my discord bot where it pings a random one of the online users.

Answer (score 2):

According to this answer, `message.guild.members` in `on_message(message)` will give you a list of all members in a server. Just choose a random entry from that list. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47733521/11591238

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get online members, you can check user status.

```
members = [m for m in guild.members if str(m.status) != "offline" or not m.bot] #this will remove offline members and bots from members
target = random.choice(members)
```